# How to extract paths in a Url string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to extract path component from url string at different depth levels.
If the input is:

```
http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/df.csv
```

Output should be:

```
    folder1_path = 'http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1'
    folder2_path = 'http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1/folder2'
    folder3_path = 'http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1/folder2/folder3' 
    folder4_path = 'http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4'
```

Output is to create 3 new string variable by doing string operation on my_url_path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a clever combination of string `split` and `join`. Something like this should work:

```
def path_to_folder_n(url, n):
  """
  url: str, full url as string
  n: int, level of directories to include from root
  """
  base = 3
  s = url.split('/')
  return '/'.join(s[:base+n])


my_url_path =   'http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/df.csv'

# folder 1
print(path_to_folder_n(my_url_path, 1))

# folder 4
print(path_to_folder_n(my_url_path, 4))

# folder 3
print(path_to_folder_n(my_url_path, 3))
```

Output:

```
>> http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1
>> http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
>> http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

Keep in mind you may want to add error checks to avoid `n` going too long.

See it in action here: https://repl.it/repls/BelovedUnhealthyBase#main.py

Answer (score 0):

For getting the parent directory from a string in this format you could simply do

```python
my_url_path.split('/')[-2]
```

For any parent you subtract the number from the index of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this function that address your problem.

It just uses `split()` and `join()` methods of the `str` class, and also the `takewhile()` function of the `itertools` module, which basically takes elements from an iterable while the predicate (its first argument) is true.

```
from itertools import takewhile


def manipulate_path(target, url):
    path_parts = url.split('/')
    partial_output = takewhile(lambda x: x != target, path_parts)
    return "/".join(partial_output) + f'/{target}'
```

You can use it as follows:

```
manipulate_path('folder1', my_url_path)    # returns 'http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1'
manipulate_path('folder2', my_url_path)    # returns 'http//10.6.7.9:5647/folder1/folder2'
```